# What is the easiest way to trigger a C# class from an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my asp.net page I have three labels:

1. A default name to filter by
2. Filled with a list of names which I want to click on to be the new filter
3. Filled with a list of items to be filtered

2 and 3 are both filled by content which is loaded in by the C# code behind it.
When the page loads, it is automatically filtered by the default text of the first label. I want to click on the other labels to call the method which is triggered on page load but filtering with the clicked on name.

My problem is that I've tried replacing the first label with whichever name is clicked on and then loading the content again which is filtered by the first label, but it seems to reset the label to it's default text obviously filtering it the same way it always does.

Perhaps AJAX is the easiest way but I haven't tried it so a basic example doing this would be great.

If you have more questions just ask.

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled for the controls? Also, are you only binding your data on initial load, not on every postback?

Comment: have some code to show us? what've you tried to do? that way would be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can use two method `Ajax Call` and `__dopostback`

1 __doPostback

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="javascript:SaveWithParameter('Hello User')"  value="click me"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 function SaveWithParameter(parameter)
  {
 __doPostBack('btnSave', parameter)
  }
 </script>
```

C# Code

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
// Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // btnSave and do your work
 }
```

2 Ajax Call

```
    function callAjaxGetJoiningDate(hashVal) {
        var address = "Default.aspx";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: address,
            data: { empCode: hashVal },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // successful request; do something with the data
                $('#ajax-panel').empty();
                var actualData = data.trim().split('~');
                $("#YourResultControl").val(actualData[1]);
            },
            error: function() {
                // failed request; give feedback to user
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
            }
        });
    }
```

C# code is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Request.Form["empCode"] != null)
        {
          //Do Work
     }
     }
```

Hope It helps you

Answer (score 1):

you can use Page Methods. You have sign your method with [WebMethod] attribute
[tutorial here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

Place all your labels in an AJAX Update Panel and do it in your code behind.